# Watch application.properties changes at runtime Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring boot app, and i want to watch for changes in application.properties at run time. For example i have property name:

name = John, Test

I am getting it with:

```
  @Value("${name}")
  String name;
```

And when i start my app it prints John and Test, and now if i add another name in run time i want to print that too.

I know it can be done with Refresh Scope but i do not want to use the /refresh endpoint to refresh it. I want to make it without sending requests.

Is there another solution?

Comment: You could use JMX and Spring's `@ManagedOperation` to create a bean that will change your value in runtime.

Comment: But I don't think that modifying application.properties in runtime is a good idea. Why would you do that?

Comment: Can you send me some example that works?

Comment: It doesn't have to be application.properties. I can use conf.properties for example another external property file.

Answer (score 0):

What could help you is JMX technology that allows connecting to running JVM remotely and accessing its exposed functions. Spring gives you a tool for that which is `@ManagedResoruce` and `@ManagedOperation` annotations.

To give you a hint, you create a bean:

```java
@ManagedResource
public class NameUpdater {
  @Value("$name")
  private String name;

  @ManagedOperation
  public void updateName(String newName) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Now, when you start your application, you can also run Java Mission Control or VisualVM which are tools provided in JDK. You should see PID of your running process and connect to it in order to access your managed bean.

Comment: I think you are missing the point.. The point is not to watch the PIDS and with jmx to change the variable.. There is some Watcher or Listener for config file that needs to alarm you if there is some change...

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that you're looking for a way to change some property value in runtime.

Comment: Anyway, I'll leave that answer. Maybe someone will find it useful.